# How can I deploy Application in geronimo 3.0.1?

Tags: geronimo

I am new to handling **geronimo**.Today I installed **geronimo 3.0.1** in my system,already I have built web-Application and it is in folder format, I don't know where to put this folder. How can I test the application whether working or not.

Thank

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion is use **deployment plan** in **Geronimo**.

Try to check out this official documentation
https://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/understanding-deployment-plans.html

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your archieve package (war file) by using **Deployer** feature of Geronino.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command line inside bin folder of geronimo:
deploy -port [port]--user [user] --password [password] deploy D:\projects\td-selection-esb\dist\td-selection-esb-*.war

After deploying successfully it will be inside the repository folder of geronimo.